# i18next always give me fallback language response

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, i18next

My Imports

```js
import i18next from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-fs-backend'
import middleware from 'i18next-http-middleware'
```

While using i18next for localization always give me fallback langauge

My requests header {Accept-Language:"ar"}
Code config

```js
i18next
  .use(Backend)
  .use(middleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    backend: {
      loadPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    },
  })
```

How I'm using this

```js
app.all('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    status: i18next.t('errorStatus'),
    message: i18next.t('error404'),
  })
})
```

It's always give me ressponse with only english response not other language file
but If I'm using like that "req.t" it's work but i need to use it like "i18next.t" for non request methodds

Comment: The global i18next instance does not know about your request related language…