# Why i18next's fallbackLng overrides changeLanguage?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, i18next

I have a node.js app & I'm trying to support multi-language based on the URL query string. I used i18next module.

This is a snippet of my main index.ts

```
...
import i18next from 'i18next';
import i18nextMiddleware from 'i18next-http-middleware';
import i18nextBackend from 'i18next-fs-backend';

...

i18next
  .use(i18nextBackend)
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    //lng: i18next.language,
    defaultNS: 'common',
    ns: ['common', 'users', 'products', 'errors'],
    /*preload: ['en', 'ar'],*/
    backend: {
      loadPath: './src/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    detection: {
      order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'header'],
      lookupQuerystring: 'lang',
    },
  });
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));
app.use((req, _res, next) => {
  const lang = req.query.lang || 'en';
  //console.log(lang)
  
  req.i18n.changeLanguage(lang as string);
  next();
});

...
```

This is how I'm using it in users controller

```
    ...
    return res.json({
      status: 'success',
      data: { ...user },
      message: i18next.t('users:successful_login'),
    });
```

- If I set `fallbackLng: ''`, I get the translation key in the API
  response `successful_login`
- If I make it `fallbackLng: 'en'`, I
  always get the English translation
- If I change it to `fallbackLng: 'ar'`, I always get the Arabic equivalent

It seems fallbackLng **ALWAYS** overrides the language change middleware

When I call any API, I see these three logs for each API call

```
   i18next: languageChanged en
   i18next: languageChanged ar
   i18next: languageChanged ar
```

It seems the language does change but still I only get whatever language in `fallbackLng`

PS: I'm not using [handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941334/why-is-i18next-http-middleware-defaulting-back-to-fallback-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for so long, and just after a few moments of posting the question here, I solved it. I think this is the blessing of good-old StackOverflow.

Jokes aside, I saw the [comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74908424/i18next-always-give-me-fallback-language-response) & thought "That makes sense".

In the controller, instead of using it like this

```
...
import i18next from 'i18next';

...
i18next.t('users:successful_login')
```

I removed the global `i18next` import & changed it to

```
req.i18n.t('users:successful_logout')
```